# jQuery load #div from page that has AngularJS content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, lazy-loading

**EDIT** Ok, guys thank you all. I now got that my approach was wrong and that jQuery and AngularJS architectures don't really bode well together. I will try to approach it with pure AngularJS way(the purpose of this was to learn Angular). You are a nice community.

I know that some people have asked something similar again, but I didn't find any solution. I am quite new in AngularJS(seems awesome btw), but I am a bit confused on how to do some basic stuff.

I want to click a button and load a div from another page. That div is populated from AngularJS MV.

My jQuery code

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){
    var elemt = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    $('#main_descr').html('');
    $('#dynamic').remove();
    $('#main_descr').load( 'moar.php #'+elemt, function(){
        //what should I do?
    });

});
```

a portion of my "AngularJS moar.php"(for example this div is getting loaded)

```
<div id="skills" class="more_info" ng-controller="skillsList">
<h2>Skills</h2>

<section ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <h3>{{skill.title}}</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="partskill in skill.skillz">{{partskill.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

my controller(note that I haven't declared an app. I load )

```
function skillsList($scope) {

$scope.skills = [
{'title': 'Science & Engineering',
 'skillz' : [
                {'name' : 'Software engineering'},
                {'name' : 'Operating Systems'},
                {'name' : 'Bio - Informatics'},
                {'name' : 'Algorithms'},
                {'name' : 'Optimization'},
                {'name' : 'RESTful services'},
                {'name' : 'Digital Design'},
                {'name' : 'Electronics'},
                {'name' : 'Wireless Sensors'},
                {'name' : 'OpNet'},
                {'name' : 'Simulations'},
                {'name' : 'Mathematics(applied, analysis etc.)'}
            ]},
{'title': 'Coding',
 'skillz' : [
                {'name' : 'Java'},
                {'name' : 'Android'},
                {'name' : 'C++'},
                {'name' : 'C'},
                {'name' : 'Python'},
                {'name' : 'Javascript'},
                {'name' : 'jQuery'},
                {'name' : 'AngularJS'},
                {'name' : 'PHP5'},
                {'name' : 'SQL'},
                {'name' : 'CSS3'},
                {'name' : 'HTML5'},
                {'name' : 'Matlab'},
                {'name' : 'ns'}
            ]},
{'title': 'Languages',
 'skillz' : [
                {'name' : 'English', 'extra' : 'Proficient'},
                {'name' : 'Greek', 'extra' : 'Native'},
                {'name' : 'Swedish', 'extra' : 'Basic'}
            ]}
];
}
```

I would love some advice, please. Help the newbie

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and angular? Why not try `ng-click=""`?

Comment: I didn't know how to take the html from the <li> so I can load the proper div. 

I am really new to Angular

Comment: Your best bet is to look into how to use routing and views. Did you go through the tutorial? Jumping right in without doing some sort of tutorial that covers controllers, views, routing, service, and directives (probably filters too) is a disservice to yourself.

Comment: yeah, few weeks ago. Maybe I should redo it. Although, routing seems not to exactly fit what I need(at least how I tried it with guide this http://jsfiddle.net/pXpja/3/), I will look at it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing AngularJS with JQuery is not a good approach. Angular is good enough to cover all your needs. With your problem I would suggest that you try adding an angular ng-include. This directive allows you to inject "HTML Pages", however, I think you will need to tweak your app a little bit.

Comment: Any code example on how to dynamically include HTML with ng-include?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified fiddle, using your html and `ng-click` to perform an action upon clicking on the `li`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yryzt/

Clicking on them should make them lowercase. No jQuery used :)

Comment: I will check it out in few mins. However. How do I make it load in a page? 

I have index.php and I want to load into "#content" a corresponding div from the page "moar.php"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Angular should be used to create single page applications. You use routing and partials to build the app, and usually only need to create a single index.html that the client loads. Checkout egghead.io for some beginner tutorials.